# How do I got from "menu" to playing the actual game?

Tags: boolean, branch, p5.js

```
/* COMP 125 Lab 12: Start-Play-GameOver

Modify this sketch so that clicking the mouse will step you through three different screens in a sequence (start, play, gameOver)

You will need to add some if() statements to the mousePressed() function to control navigation.

Also, you will need to add some simple graphics (a background, a simple picture, some text ...) to each screen function (scroll down)
*/

// boolean "flag" variables (global) var start = true; // the game will begin on the "start" screen var play = false; var gameOver = false;

clickX = 0; // track the mouse click location clickY = 0;

function setup() {   createCanvas(640, 480); }

function draw() {   //Leave this draw() function alone   if (start){
    // only if true AND the other flags are false
    startScreen();   }    else if (play){ 
    // only if true AND the other flags are false
    playScreen();    }   else if (gameOver){
    // only if true AND the other flags are false
    gameOverScreen();    }  }

function mousePressed(){   // don't change this one either!   clickX = mouseX; // grab the X location of the mouse   clickY = mouseY; // grab the Y location of the mouse }

function startScreen(){   // 1. add code here to display something on screen    background(50);   textSize(20);   fill(255, 0, 0);   text('To begin playing, click mouse',60,80);   // 2. add a conditional statement that switches to the play screen
     /*******   if you want to use the mouse click to control things, you can check the location of clickX and clickY against another location, e.g.:   if(dist(clickX, clickY, width/2, height/2) < 100){
    //set the start, play, and gameOver flags to EITHER true or false
    // reset clickX and clickY to 0   }
     *******/   }

function playScreen(){   // 1. add code here to display something on screen    // 2. add a conditional statement to move to game over state }

function gameOverScreen(){   // 1. add code here to display something on screen    // 2. add a conditional statement to move back to either play or start

}
```

add some branching logic to the mousePressed() function so that mouse clicks will change the canvas from one screen to the next. Think about how to use if() and else if() statements and those boolean "flag" variables at the top of the sketch (8 points). How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly add something similar to a counter in the mousePressed() function.
As an example:

```
let a = 0;

function mousePressed(){
a++;
if(a==1){
 //do xyz
  }
if(a==2){
 //do xyz
  }
if(a==3){
  //do xyz
  a=0; //To reset the game.
 }
}
```